# change the background colour of divs when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have tabs comprised of the following, When I clicked on any of the divs, I need background colour change to blue and if I clicke on other div, the previous tabs colour needs to set to original and new clicked div colour to be blue and so on:

This is my html:

```
                          <div class="zoom_controls">
                              <a class="db" id="prof_cpu_d" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="1m">Real Time</a>
                              <a class="db" id="prof_cpu_w"href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="3m">Weekly</a>
                              <a class="db" id="prof_cpu_m" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="6m">Monthly</a>
                        </div>
```

I have this:

```
.zoom_controls a:active {
            background-color: #a6d1ff;
}
```

it does not seem to be working

how would I do this in css?

Comment: Impossible with CSS only. You need JavaScript.

Comment: You say you want to click on `div`s, but you show *one* `div` containing a bunch of `a` elements; what, exactly, do you want to happen in response to what? What's your *actual* (representative) HTML?

Comment: active will only work while you hold the click button down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Javascript/jQuery to toggle the class. You can't do this with pure CSS.

**Modify CSS**

```
.zoom_controls a.active {
  background-color: #a6d1ff;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.zoom_controls a').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $('.zoom_controls a').removeClass('active'); //Remove color for all with class .zoom_controls
  $(this).toggleClass('active'); //Apply bgcolor to clicked element
});
```

[Codepen sketch](http://cdpn.io/HAEiD)

**Update**
If you are, for some reason, thinking about `a:hover`, then you do it like this in CSS.

```
.zoom_controls a:hover {
  background-color: #a6d1ff;
}
```

Otherwise, if you are looking to target the 'active' state of the link, you are doing it correctly.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. not working for me, when I move the browser, the colour moves back to the original. I need it to be stayed as blue when I clicked.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: I found out the problem. I was doing this: .zoom_controls a { backgound-colour:black}, once I removed this it is working now. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `:active` state only applies when the anchor is *active* -- that is, when the user is clicking on it. When that click ends, so does the state. What you want can't be done with pure CSS.

**CSS**:

```
.zoom_controls a.active {
  background-color: #a6d1ff;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('.zoom_controls a').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

**[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/OniHeKo/1/edit)**

Comment: Rash, I did exactly as you suggested, the same result, nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library included in your source? If so, there must be something else happening in your application. The demo I linked to does what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JS library jquery to select the active tabs and assign the the background color.  The nice bit with using jquery is it's compatibility with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* work, but it's not doing what you want. Because `active` is only a [dynamic pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) that determines the styling of an *active* element (in this case any link inside the div with class `zoom_controls` when it's being clicked).

You might need JavaScript for this job, that or an unnecessarily complex CSS 3 solution.